# How can I sort my image - the latest on top

Tags: php, image

I found on YT a php code to display images from directory.
Everything works perfect, but I need to display the latest photos on the top. 
Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
    $dir = 'foto';
    $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg');

    if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
        echo 'Gallery \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
    } else {
        $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

        foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
            $file_type = strtolower (end(explode('.', $file)));

            if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
                echo '<div id="', $file,  '"><img src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '" /></div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to look into the PHP filemtime function, in order to pull out the modified date of a file - I don't think that's possible with scandir alone. Then look here http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php for information regarding sorting arrays, and piecing those together you should be able to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923235/scandir-to-sort-by-date-modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less code:

```
array_multisort((
    array_map(
        'filemtime', ($files = glob(
            "$dir/*.{jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE)))), SORT_DESC, $files);
```

- Glob for the specific files and store in `$files`
- Get the file modification time for each and sort `$files` on the times

`foreach` on `$files` and display.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to sort images by date. Someone has written another variant of `scandir()` function here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923516/1644017

You can get that function and change `$dir_contents = scandir($dir);` to: `$dir_contents = scan_dir($dir);` in your code.